# Reduce a json string column into a key/val column

Tags: scala, apache-spark

i have a dataframe with the following structure :

```
| a        | b    |           c                                             |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|01        |ABC   |    {"key1":"valueA","key2":"valueC"}                    |
|02        |ABC   |    {"key1":"valueA","key2":"valueC"}                    |
|11        |DEF   |    {"key1":"valueB","key2":"valueD", "key3":"valueE"}   |
|12        |DEF   |    {"key1":"valueB","key2":"valueD", "key3":"valueE"}   |
```

i would like to turn into something like :

```
| a        | b    |      key         |       value     |
--------------------------------------------------------
|01        |ABC   |    key1          |     valueA      |
|01        |ABC   |    key2          |     valueC      |
|02        |ABC   |    key1          |     valueA      |
|02        |ABC   |    key2          |     valueC      |
|11        |DEF   |    key1          |     valueB      |
|11        |DEF   |    key2          |     valueD      |
|11        |DEF   |    key3          |     valueE      |
|12        |DEF   |    key1          |     valueB      |
|12        |DEF   |    key2          |     valueD      |
|12        |DEF   |    key3          |     valueE      |
```

in an efficient way, as the dataset can be quite large.

Comment: Note, key1...keyXX are consistent only for a given col(b) value

Comment: using spark 3.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using **`from_json`** function then **`explode`** the array.

**`Example:`**

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val df=Seq(("01","ABC","""{"key1":"valueA","key2":"valueC"}""")).toDF("a","b","c")
val Schema = MapType(StringType, StringType)
df.withColumn("d",from_json(col("c"),Schema)).selectExpr("a","b","explode(d)").show(10,false)
//+---+---+----+------+
//|a  |b  |key |value |
//+---+---+----+------+
//|01 |ABC|key1|valueA|
//|01 |ABC|key2|valueC|
//+---+---+----+------+
```

Comment: Brilliant... much appreciate. i was starting to look building an UDF to parse the json string into a map. sounds from_json is much more powerfull.